# From TexShop to LyX - Table error

Tags: tables, lyx

I wrote this table in TexShop and all seems to work but, when I try to insert this table in a Tex block in LyX I got some *Undefined Control sequences*, some *Missing $ inserted* and some *extra}*

I used, in the lyx preamble, the following packeges:

```
\usepackage{babel}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{chngpage}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{multirow}
```

Any ideas why Lyx is so fussy?

```
\begin{table}[htdp]
\begin{small}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|cc|cc|cc|}
\hline
\multicolumn{6}{|l|}{\footnotesize - Società con 26 milioni di ricavi, 10 milioni di attivo e un milione di capitale sociale - durante l'anno}\\
\multicolumn{6}{|l|}{\footnotesize si sono svolte n. 4 riunioni del CdA e n. 1 assemblea, di durata di 2 ore cadauna per un totale di 10}\\
\multicolumn{6}{|l|}{\footnotesize ore di presenza - i sindaci applicano un calcolo di rimborso per spese generali studio e viaggi pari a euro}\\
\multicolumn{6}{|l|}{\footnotesize  500,00 cadauno}\\
\hline
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\textbf{Collegio Sindacale}} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\textbf{Collegio Sindacale}} &  \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\textbf{Sindaco Unico}}\\
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\textbf{con applicazione art.37}} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\textbf{con applicazione art.29}} &  \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\textbf{con applicazione art.29}}\\
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\textbf{vecchia tariffa}} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\textbf{nuovi parametri}} &  \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\textbf{nuovi parametri}}\\ \hline

\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Onorario per attività} & \multirow{2}{*}{\euro\; 3750} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Onorario per funzione} & \euro\; 8000 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Onorario per funzione} & \multirow{2}{*}{\euro\;11100}\\
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{di controllo ex art.2403 c.c} & & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{sindacale} &+3100& \multicolumn{1}{l|}{sindacale} &\\
\hline

\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Onorario per relazione} & \multirow{2}{*}{\euro\;4600} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{--}} & \multirow{2}{*}{--} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Maggiorazione per carica} &\multirow{2}{*}{\euro\;11100}\\
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{al bilancio} & & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{di sindaco unico} & \\\hline

\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Onorario per partecipazioni} & \multirow{2}{*}{\euro\;1150} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{--}} & \multirow{2}{*}{--} &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{}} & \multirow{2}{*}{}\\
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{riunioni} & & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & &  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \\\hline

\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Rimborsi spese} & \multirow{1}{*}{\euro\;500} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{1}{*}{--}} & \multirow{1}{*}{--} &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{}} & \multirow{2}{*}{}\\\hline

\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Tot. Membro collegio} & \multirow{1}{*}{\euro\;10400} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Tot. Membro collegio} & \multirow{1}{*}{\euro\;11100} &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{}} & \multirow{2}{*}{}\\\hline

\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Tot. Collegio} & \multirow{2}{*}{\euro\; 36400} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Tot. Collegio} & \euro\; 38850 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\multirow{2}{*}{Totale}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\euro\;22200}\\
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{(+50\% al presidente)} & & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(+50\% al presidente)} & & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} &\\
\hline

\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\caption{\footnotesize Ipotesi di calcolo compenso Collegio Sindacale}
\label{default}
\end{small}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the euro symbol. You should change the preamble entry to: `\usepackage[gennarrow]{eurosym}`

Have a look at [this](http://elyxer.nongnu.org/lyx/Math.html#toc-Subsection-13.3) site. I suggest to replace the `\euro\;` parts with `\officialeuro ~` since you are in text mode.

With this changes your table worked fine for me. The lines of yours should look something like this example one:

```
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Onorario per attività} & \multirow{2}{*}{\officialeuro ~ 3750} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Onorario per funzione} & \officialeuro  8000 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Onorario per funzione} & \multirow{2}{*}{\officialeuro 11100}
```

Btw: You should consider using https://tex.stackexchange.com/ for latex related questions the next time.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks and sorry for the wrong posting ;)